# Time differences in java jsf

Tags: java, date

I have stored time with the format as "20:01:00" as double.

I can i calculate the different 2 of the above time.

Such that variable1 = 18:20:00
Variable2 = 19:22:00

So if variable1 is more than variable2 it will perform some action.

How can i do it in java?

Comment: Would you please post some code example? The question isn't very clear I'm afraid.

Comment: no coding yet.. This was the requirement that i have to put into code...

Comment: @benylim Why you are storing time as double?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class instead. It has methods like [after()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after%28java.util.Date%29), which is way better than your compare implementations. Storing a time as double is just plain wrong(because of different time zones, etc).

Answer (score 2):

If you are receiving the time as a string format you mention, you can use SimpleDateFormat to create a Date object as mentioned above, then use methods like compareTo(Date anotherDate) or even just subtract one time from another. Something like:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
Date date1 = df.parse(stringDate1);
Date date2 = df.parse(stringDate2);
if (date1.compareTo(date2) < 0) {
    # date1 is before date2 
} else if (date1.compareTo(date2) > 0) {
    # date1 is after date2
} else {
    # they are the same
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Date as a double?  That is something new, and I thought I have seen everything :(

Don't do that.  The class [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) is little more than a `long` timestamp with deprecated methods that you should not use.  The value of this timestamp is a `long` primitive that represents milliseconds from the epoch (January 1, 1970 00:00:00 GMT).  This is a whole number at millisecond precision so please do not store it as a `double`, you will make the compiler cry.

For simplicity sake, you can look at the [Apache Commons DateUtils class](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html) for convenient and helpful methods when working with Dates and Calendars.